# Separate two signals using python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, signal-processing

Are there any libraries which deal with separating signals? I have a scatter graph where there appears to be two separate signals, I'd like to separate these signals and then fit a curve to each separately.

Here: are three scatter graphs to try to illustrate what I mean:

[image]

The leftmost is the data, the middle is the data with some lines drawn in paint roughly tracing the two signals and the rightmost is a curve of best fit drawn using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`. I'd like to separate the two signals as they interfere with the nonlinear regression, my current solution is to just use data below the mean on the x-axis for one `curve_fit`, and data above for a second `curve_fit`. I was just wondering if there was a better way (using Python).

I'm using the Enthought Canopy Distribution of Python.

Comment: That is a very broad question so here is a very broad answer. [Scipy](http://www.scipy.org/) (Scientific Python) is a great toolkit for many many things. [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) is a python distribution that already includes Scipy among many other useful libraries. If you want more detail, you'll need to share detail about your inputs, the outputs you expect, what you have tried and what problems you are having.

Comment: Thanks for your response. [Here](http://imgur.com/I5qNq3Q) are three scatter graphs to try to illustrate what I mean. The leftmost is the data, the middle is the data with some lines drawn in paint roughly tracing the two signals and the rightmost is a curve of best fit drawn using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`. I'd like to separate the two signals as they interfere with the nonlinear regression, my current solution is to just use data below the mean on the x-axis for one `curve_fit`, and data above for a second `curve_fit`. I was just wondering if there was a better way (using Python).

Comment: if you took out the programming language-specific material, this question might be a better fit on stats.se. The important part of your question is what technique to use to separate the signals (if indeed they can be separated), not whether you use Python, R, Matlab or whatever to do the job.

Comment: @Bprodz Agreed with TooTone. I suggest you ask this in non-programming terms on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) to see what techniques would be best based on the properties of your data. I guess you will need to include more detail about your data sources/properties, why you suspect that there are two signals, and in what way you suspect that they are different. Once you have that, if you can't find a way to do it with Scipy, you can ask here about how to implement the operation. This is not to dump your problem on someone else - that forum will just be more able to answer.

Comment: @Bprodz actually, depending on the details of how you think the signals are different, you might get better luck on the [Signal Processing Exchange](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/)